# php Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object problem

Tags: php, database

```
<?php
    $dbtype = 'mysql';
    $mysql_host = "localhost";
    $mysql_database = "mydb";
    $mysql_user = "root";
    $mysql_password = "";
    try {
        $db = new PDO ( $dbtype . ':host=' . $mysql_host . ';dbname=' . $mysql_database,         $mysql_user, $mysql_password, array (PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true ) );
        return $db;
    } catch ( PDOException $e ) {
        return false;
    }
?>
```

Above are my db.php

```
<?php
   require db.php";
   ...
   global $db;
   $stmt = $db->prepare ( "INSERT INTO quote (title, contactname) VALUES (:a, :b);" );
```

I actually able to run it properly under my IDE (ZendStudo wamp server) but once i upload to host server i got this error. Anybody facing the same problem before can guide me how to fix?

Comment: What are you returning false to if your db connect code throws an exception?

Comment: check PDO extention using phpinfo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There can me many reasons, but one obivious is that is you had a PDOException, then `$db == false`, which would explain the error message.

Try to check if `$db` is correctly set as a `PDO` or `false`.

Comment: Thanks, is the $db never set properly due to wrong value pass in.

Answer (score 0):

PDO does not throw exceptions unless you explicitly instruct it to do so:

```
$db = new PDO(...);
$db ->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```